# does python 3 multiprocessing freeze_support() sets the starting method to spawn?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-multiprocessing

well recently I encountered some freezing in my applications in Long run.
my program uses an infinite while loop to constantly check for new processes from a `redis` db and if there is any job to work on it will spawns a new process to run it in the background.

so I had issue with its freezing after 20 minutes, sometimes 10 minutes. it took me one week to figure it out that the problem rise from lack of this line before my while loop:

```
multiprocessing.set_start_method('spawn')
```

it looks like python does not do that on Windows and since windows does not support fork it's gonna stuck.

anyway, it seems this will solve my problem but I have another question.

in order to make a `exe` file for this program with something like `pyinstaller` I need to add another line as below to make sure its not freezing in the exe execution:

```
multiprocessing.freeze_support()
```

I want to know does this `freeze_support()` automatically sets the start method to `'spawn'` too? I mean should I use both of these lines or just running one of them is ok? if so which one should I use from now on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of windows, spawn is already the default method so it would not be necessary to run the set_start_method ('spawn') line of code.
The freeze_support () is a different thing that does not affect the definition of start methods. You must use it in this scenario to generate an .exe.